# What should i make for Passive Past

Tags: passive-voice

Sir, i've been wondering, what should i write for passive and in past tense, for sentence : I stay for the sermon.

1. I stay for the sermon (active present)
2. I stayed for the sermon (active past)
3. For the sermon i stayed (passive present)
4. ........................   (passive past)

I have used the 2nd form of the verb stay. What should i do?

Please, need your help so much sir.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

(Posting an answer because the system won't let me comment.)

No. 3 is neither passive nor the present tense. *Stay* is an intransitive verb, so it can't be used in the passive voice.

Somebody else might *make* you stay, in which case you would have to say 'I was made to stay for the sermon' (past tense) or 'I am being made to stay for the sermon' (present tense).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer mam, but can you give an example of a verb that is not intransive, for passive voice both present and past. Let say : i pay for the sermon.

Comment: That would be *The sermon is paid for by me.*

Comment: Thank you so much sir.